# Can we write json key with space like(first name)

Tags: json

Can we write json key with space like `first name`?
Below is the sample json:

```
[
  {
    "first_name": "James"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Tom"
  }
]
```

Comment: "first name" as a key is valid

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, it is valid `RFC 8259`, however it will make more difficult to use in some languages, for example in PHP you want be able to use the arrow operator to access the data.
This obviously won't make this JSON not valid.